PyAutoGUI Image not found
I have the image im trying to search for in my project directory. made sure the program is using the working directory and it still is giving me an image not found exception.
def joinListenerGo():
    print("Join Listener Starting please have ark open.")
    join_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'JoinUpdated.png')
    someonejoined = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('joiner.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.8)
    if someonejoined != None:
        print("Someone Joined")
        pyautogui.click(someonejoined)
        pyautogui.write("Someone joined the ark server")

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hades\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hades\PycharmProjects\AlbionGathering\.venv\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_switch.py", line 413, in toggle
    self._command()
  File "C:\Users\Hades\PycharmProjects\AlbionGathering\main.py", line 58, in <lambda>
    joinerOn = CTkSwitch(master=joiner, text="Join Listener", command=lambda: joinListenerGo())
                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hades\PycharmProjects\AlbionGathering\main.py", line 65, in joinListenerGo
    someonejoined = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('joiner.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.8)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hades\PycharmProjects\AlbionGathering\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 174, in wrapper
    raise ImageNotFoundException  # Raise PyAutoGUI's ImageNotFoundException.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException

Made sure it was using the working directory for the image (it was) I expected it to be able to see the image but it cannot.

Something new i tried is this...
    if os.path.exists('./joiner.png'):
        print("Image file exists")
    else:
        print("Image file does not exist")

This shows and does print that the image file does exist

After doing more testing i was able to get it working using a while True statement with a try catch

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
